# Website Title Help

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on adjusting my site title in Wordpress. I want my site title to admit the "Home  >>" text from the title only on the homepage. Here is the code that i'm working with:

```
<title><?php if ( is_home() ) { ?> <?php } ?>  <?php echo ucwords(wp_title('',false)); ?> &raquo; <?php echo ucwords(get_bloginfo('name')); ?>  </title>
```

As i'm new to php, I'm trying decypher the coding. Would an if-else statement serve better?

```
 <title><?php if ( is_home() ) 
                echo "Blah blah blah";
              else
                echo "<?php echo ucwords(wp_title('',false)); ?>
   &raquo; <?php echo      
   ucwords(get_bloginfo('name')); ?>";
 ?></title>


{ ?> <?php } ?> 
    <?php echo ucwords(wp_title('',false)); ?> &raquo; <?php echo ucwords(get_bloginfo('name')); ?> 
</title>
```

I would greatly appreciate your opinion. My website is http://www.merrimentdesign.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<title>
<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?> Home title, you don't need to echo something <?php } ?>
<?php echo ucwords(wp_title('',false)); ?> &raquo; 
<?php echo ucwords(get_bloginfo('name')); ?>  
</title>
```

**Edit:**

```
<title>
    <?php 
         if ( is_home() ) { //I'm in the homepage 
    ?> 
             Home title, you don't need to echo something
    <?php
        }else{ //every page but homepage
            echo ucwords(wp_title('',false)) . '&raquo;' . ucwords(get_bloginfo('name'));
        }
    ?>
</title>
```

Comment: This seems to repeat when I implement it. Title keeps going.

Comment: I think I see the problem, but am unsure how to fix this. I would like ONLY that first line of code to be the title of my homepage and if not, then print the next two lines. I'm not too familiar with syntax of PHP so i'm unsure how to make it a if-else.

Comment: For some odd reason, I can't seem to get this to work in firefox. It does however work in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

An inline comparison would serve you well

```
<title>
<?php 
echo (ishome()? "isHome evaluated to true": "isHome evaluated to false");
?>
</title>
```

Additionally nested PHP tags will not work and will simply throw errors.

IE

```
<?PHP
//everything in here is already php, if you add this:
echo "echo <?php doSomething(); ?>";
?>
```

Will not work because the ?> tag within your "echo" statement will be treated by PHP as the end of the PHP code block, not a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
echo "<?php echo ucwords(wp_title('',false));
```

just do

```
echo ucwords(wp_title('',false));
```

You can't echo PHP tags and have them be executed as PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I do in my blog.  But it won't work like it is - change it to:

```
<title><?php if ( is_home() )
                 echo "Blah blah blah";
             else
                 echo ucwords(wp_title('',false)); ?>    
&raquo; 

<?php echo ucwords(get_bloginfo('name')); ?></title>
```